# attr_encrypted and postgresql, does it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, rubygems, postgresql-9.1

Des attr_encryptor (or attr_encrypted) works with Postgresql ?
Datas are not saved, when I wrote

```
@object.encrypted_value
```

I have something but it is never saved... Or maybe I am doing something wrong ?

My model looks like :

```
Model User < Activerecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email
  attr_encrypted :email, :key => "asecretkey"
end
```

In my DDB, I have User(name, encrypted_email, encrypted_email_iv, encrypted_email_salt) with character varying(255) for each.

And my form is like c.email (and not c.encrypted_email, is that right ?)

Answer (score 0):

What does your model look like? If you have a `@object.my_value = 'thing'` then your model should look roughly like

```
class MyObject
  attr_encrypted :my_value, :key => 'a secret key'
end
```

Don't forget to call `#save` on an object after assigning a value. You should be able to get the encrypted payload back with `@object.encrypted_my_value` if you want. The DB will also need a string field called encrypted_my_value.

Comment: So when you call @object.save it isn't saving the encrypted data to the DB? (which in your case would be a field called encrypted_email)

Comment: With better_errors, when I wrote "@user", I don't have any value for email but when I wrote "@user.email or @user.encrypted_email", I have. Is it normal ?

When I save, I have an error because the field "email" doesn't exist, which is normal because it is "encrypted_email"...

Comment: Change your model to remove :email from your attr_accessible list. attr_encrypted provides the getter (and auto-decrypts the value) for you.

Comment: Without it, I have an error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email"

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. Which gem are you using now? Have you tried https://github.com/danpal/attr_encryptor (current version 2.0) rather than the old attr_encrypted? You'll need to add _iv and _salt fields to your DB as well if you use that gem.

Comment: I tried with a migration test:string and it works. In fact I think it was just with email value... of course. Thanks anyway.